# Expecting expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, django

I'm having an issue on my django app however, it seems to be more of a python issue, although I don't see where the issue lies

This is my code

```
 for q in qs:

        untouched_question_in_term_of_minutes = (now() - q.date) #take the current date 
        #and substract the date when the question was created
        certain_mn_ago = untouched_question_in_term_of_minutes.total_seconds() / 60 
        #that gives me the number of minutes where 
        #the question has not been touched
        limit_of_mn = 50
        print(untouched_question_in_term_of_minutes)
        print(certain_mn_ago)

        if certain_mn_ago >= limit_of_mn: 
        #if the  condition is fulfilled, then the action below are done
            ae = AssociatedExpert.objects.filter(question=q, state='P')
            ae.update(state='C')
            Question.objects.filter(id=q.id, state='P').update(state='C')

            qs.filter(date__lte=certain_mn_ago, state='C').update(email='***',
                                             first_name='***',
                                             last_name='***',
                                             phone='***',
                                             extra='***')
        else:
            ae = AssociatedExpert.objects.filter(question=q,
                                                 state__in=['D', 'T', 'A',
                                                            'F']).first()
            if ae:
                qs.filter(id=q.id).update(state=ae.state)
```

As you see, the logic seems to bere here. Yet, it is giving me the traceback below.

```
TypeError at /temp_app/question/
expected string or bytes-like object
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/temp_app/question/
Django Version: 2.0.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
expected string or bytes-like object
Exception Location: 
/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py in parse_datetime, line 107
Python Executable:  /home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:    
['/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/findoor_backend',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python36.zip',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/src/django-s3-upload',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/andykw/.ipython',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/andykw/cloned_projects/findoor-backend/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odf']
Server time:    Thu, 25 Apr 2019 11:49:27 +0200
```

I thought about using to cast `untouched_question_in_term_of_minutes` and `certain_mn_ago` as `int` but the issue is still here.

The funny part is when I'm using the `ipdb`, everything seems to be ok.

If you have any ideas, I'm all ear.

**update** : I have found the issue. It is this `date__lte` part that is creating the problem.

Comment: Is the posted code what you're running? `two_days_ago` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Hi @endre, it is this that is causing the issue date_lte

Comment: @AndyK We could provide better help if you add the full error stacktrace; in the stacktrace you can identify which line exactly raises the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, the variable `certain_mn_ago` is a `float` because of the division.

```
certain_mn_ago = untouched_question_in_term_of_minutes.total_seconds() / 60
```

Then you use that `float` value to filter a field called `date` (which I would assume is some kind of `DateField`):

```
qs.filter(date__lte=certain_mn_ago, ...
```

This is most likely the cause of your error, because you cannot compare a `float` to a `DateField`.

Comment: Well, the post and the comments only mention that he found which line raises the issue; I tried to expand on why that line was causing the issue.

Comment: Hi @Ralf, many thanks. Your explanation made it clearer. Cheers. Points are yours.